# How to Convert Base64 of BigInt.js Properly To Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, biginteger, type-conversion, bigint

I am using Leemon Baird's BigInt.js [(documentation)](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js) to handle big integers. I need to be able to arrive to the same integer from BigInt into Ruby.

Example JS file:

```
var number = "1234567890987654321";
var bigNumber = str2bigInt(number, 10, 80); //10: input = Decimal
var bigNumber64 = bigInt2str(bigNumber, 64); //64: ouput = Base64
console.log(bigNumber64);
//--> 14Y4FInR1on
```

Example Ruby file:

```
big_number_64 = '14Y4FInR1on'
big_number = Base64.decode64(big_number_64) #input: Base64: output: decoded string
big_number = big_number.unpack('B*').first #B*: output = Binary
big_number = big_number.to_i(2) #read big_number as binary, output = integer
puts big_number
#--> 26313825004518719100904402231695296969994
```

My problem is that I need this to be equal

```
1234567890987654321 != 26313825004518719100904402231695296969994
```

I've tried

```
big_number = big_number_64.unpack('m*').first.unpack('B*').first
```

And tried reversing the process and checking Base64 == Base64 instead of Decimal == Decimal, and I can't seem to still make them equal.

Please help.

Comment: It is vital that I need to convert the 'big number' first into Base64 as I am passing it as a parameter through AJAX to send to the Ruby server. I think I need to convert it to binary first in this line big_number = big_number.unpack('B*').first since it's still a binary-string just before it. Please guide me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Client-side, it's just a string. You have absolutely no need for BigInt.js. Just send the string to the server and let Ruby convert it to an integer. Unless your question doesn't actually reflect your need, and you *do* need integer arithmetic or the like on the client.

Comment: Yes, the real code is much more complex than this. I use BigInt.js to calculate a Diffie-Hellman Public Key which is of `bigint` object type. And I can't pass the object itself to the server. I tried sending it as an integer, but I had a problem (i think it is because the decimal-base Public Key is very very long enough to be able to pass it as GET parameter) That's why I thought of converting it first to Base64.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too :) maybe I'll just stick with the base(36) you've shown me. Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the parameter through Ajax, it's just a string. All you need is a format that Ruby can understand and cast to an integer.

Ruby understands integers of arbitrary length, so you can send it as `1234567890987654321` and call [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i).

If you're interested in reducing the length of the string representation, you could convert it to base 36 (the highest base that Ruby can interpret) like this:

**JS**

```
var number = "1234567890987654321";
var bigNumber = str2bigInt(number, 10, 80); //10: input = Decimal
var bigNumber36 = bigInt2str(bigNumber, 36); //36: output = Base 36
console.log(bigNumber36);
//---> "9do1sjhjpei9"
```

**Ruby**

```
big_number_36 = '9do1sjhjpei9'
big_number = big_number_36.to_i(36)
puts big_number
# => 1234567890987654321
```